# Best way to verify that an option is supported by a command

Tags: command

I would like to verify that a command in a given host supports a given option, in a robust way.

My use-case is verifying that the local **`nc`** command supports the `-w` timeout option.

My first idea is to run the command with the option, then check against the returned value:

```
<command> <option> ...
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "NOT SUPPORTED"
```

This method is in conflict with *other* reasons of error which might yield a non-zero value in return.

For instance, I have a listening Unix socket on  `192.168.1.122:3888`, while on my localhost I want to test the timeout **`nc`** option (which we suppose is not supported):

```
> nc 192.168.1.122 3999 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null
> echo $?
1
> nc 192.168.1.122 3888 -w 1 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null
> echo $?
1
```

You see, from the returned value, I would not discern between a wrong port error situation, and a wrong call due to unsupported argument.

---

Are there other, maybe preferred, options?

Comment: Crazy, possibly unreliable idea: `man nc | grep — -w`

Comment: Have no `man` option! (some hosts might me embedded, eg. BusyBox)

Comment: `nc -h |& grep -e -w`? With `-h`,  Busybox nc complains about an unrecognized option and prints available options (exit status 1), `nc.openbsd` and `nc.traditional` on Ubuntu both print available options (but exit status 0).

Comment: In `nc`’s case it seems safe to rely on `-w` being present: the first release had it, and even Busybox’s re-implementation has it. This doesn’t address the general question obviously.

Comment: @muru That is not working well on a BusyBox (1.x here) installation: the `--help` option shows a usage oneliner, so at least I'd need some more regexp processing in order to extract the one string of options to grep for.

Comment: @StephenKitt Not in my BusyBox (1.23.2 here). Here `nc` simply accepts no extra option, apart from IP and port.

Comment: Oh wow, right, Busybox can be compiled without `nc` extensions (`NC_EXTRA`), which include `-w`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the behavior of commands with regards to command line handling differs wildly, it is impossible to create a general solution. For each case, you need to find ways to decide which command line switches are actually supported. If you want to protect against catastrophic behavior (for example, some uncommon version of nc that does bad things when called with a -w option) your only option is to maintain a list of known versions with their supported command line switches, and refuse to work with a command version that's not in this list :-)

Comment: +1 for the general “it’s impossible” answer; your conclusion begs the question of how to determine what version is present...

Comment: In general, that's impossible, too :-) If you can be certain that the `nc` command has been installed using the standard package manager of the host system, you might be able to ask the package manager in a safe way about the installed command.

Comment: My point exactly ;-). Even using the package manager isn’t a guarantee (*e.g.* on Debian and derivatives you’d also have to check `dpkg-divert` etc., and even then you could be facing a sysadmin who just overwrites binaries).